# JIB - Is it possible to see the dockerfile jib creates behind the scenes?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, jib

Is it possible to see the dockerfile jib creates behind the scenes ?  If yes then where and how can i locate it ?

Context - I am bit familiar with docker file and want to make sure the docker file that gets generated has everything required for my app to run successfully.

Comment: are you using jib-cli?

Comment: Nope, i am using jib meven plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jib does not generate `Dockerfile` or make any use of Docker during image building. You don't need to install Docker to use Jib.

For a normal project, if a `Dockefile` existed, some part of it would roughly look like [this](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/blob/master/docs/faq.md#what-would-a-dockerfile-for-a-jib-built-image-look-like). However, do note that the `Dockerfile` in the link is mostly for informational purposes; almost all the time, there cannot be a `Dockerfile` that can accurately reproduce the image generated by Jib.

Related, note that the way Jib works is [fundamentally different](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/issues/2383#issuecomment-617251882) than Docker's:

> the way Jib builds an image is fundamentally different from how the Docker CLI builds an image using `Dockerfile` (reproducible vs. non-reproducible, declarative vs. imperative, Docker and Dockerfile-less build vs. requiring Docker daemon and client, requiring root-privilege vs. not). Jib is in a very different realm ...

---

UPDATE: if you want to examine the built image, check out [dive](https://github.com/wagoodman/dive).